# Update parent window elments in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading popup within window and and on that popup i further load another jquery dialog box.Now my my problem is that i want to update the parent window some portion of html and don't know how to do it.If not clear ask me .thanks in advance.I want to update some div with specific id.I Added the image of my working .You can see three windows.I want to update top links (`My cart`) on either checkout or continue shopping button click.Hope now you got my point

Dialog box code :

```
jQuery("#dialog").html(data.status + ": " + data.message+"<br/><div style=' margin-top:28px; width:360px;'>
<a class='list_to_cart' href='javascript:void(0)'  onClick='parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); gotopage();' style='width:137px !important; float: left; margin-right:3px;'> Continue Shopping</a>
&nbsp; <a class='list_to_cart' href='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>checkout/cart/'  style='float: left; margin-left:50px;' onClick='parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); gotocartpage();'>Checkout</a></div>");
```

js code where i want to update :

```
 function gotopage()
 { 
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '12';
        jQuery( '#dialog' ).dialog('close');
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Do it using IDs and classes of your parent popup's elements.

Comment: i tried like this but not work `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '12';`.

Comment: it show that content is null.means not defined here

Comment: please provide some code via Plunker

Comment: @WalterBrand check now the code.

Comment: provide fiddle if possible

Comment: @Manish it is not possible to provide the fiddle due to length and complex code

Comment: Why do you use document.getElementById when you use jQuery? $("#content") does the same.

Comment: try $("#dialog").parents("#parentdivid").find("#content").html("html"); if possible

Comment: @WalterBrand that's why i said that i try every code to change html but not work.

Comment: @Manish no luck with your code.Check my qustion with image and little more details.

Comment: console.log everything. probally some element is not matching

Comment: @JFit i didn't get you ? can you explain little more

Comment: Just saying @Adda that maybe theres a selector thats returning undefined or something - so console.log(...) everything.. all your selectors, seperatly also.. you can do so in the "Console" area of Chrome developer toolbar.. (hit F12 in chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confuse in two windows.one iframe and other one your parent window.You can access your parent elements like this:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '8';
```

Try, i hope it will solve your problem.